# On destroying the horizon of a Reissner-Nordstrom black hole

Tags: black-holes, mass, charge, event-horizon, reissner-nordstrom-metric

Consider a Reissner-Nordstrom black hole with $Q<M$, so that it has a well defined event horizon, the metric for such a black hole is given by (for $\theta=0, and ~d\phi=0$):
$$ds^{2}~=~-g(r)dt^{2}+g(r)^{-1}dr^{2}$$
where, $g(r)=\left(1-\frac{2GM}{r}+\frac{GQ^2}{r^2}\right)$.

Now, let us drop a small object of mass, $m$, and charge, $q$, such that the final mass and the charge of the black hole is $M'=M+m$, and $Q'=Q+q$ respectively. Won't this experiment of ours destroy the horizon of the black hole? For the horizon to be stable, we would need to establish that $Q'<M'$, how do we go about proving the same? Can this concept be extended to the Kerr-Neumann black hole?

Comment: I can't write an answer right now but this is answered in section 33.8 of Misner, Thorne and Wheeler, where they show that, at least for an extremal black hole, you can't in fact destroy the horizon.